# Negative margin issue with Webkit columns

Tags: css, webkit, margin

I am trying to have an image which overhangs from the text – which works fine in IE and FF. In Webkit browsers however, as soon as you add columns to the equation it seems to break the layout.

Check it : http://cdpn.io/mfAtg

Comment: You'd need to position the image differently to achieve this effect without messing up the rest of the content. Try playing around with position absolute or relative.

Comment: Hey Coop, cheers for the reply. It is positioned relative, and I have tried the absolute version which works, but then the text doesn't runaround. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

add this style to the image:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```